# Radcombo box not preserved the selected item value

Tags: asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid, radcombobox

```
    <telerik:RadComboBox ID="radcmb" runat="server" MarkFirstMatch="true">
    </telerik:RadComboBox> 

            radcmb.Items.Clear();
            radcmb.Text = String.Empty;
            radcmb.DataSource = DS;
            radcmb.DataTextField ="DESCRIPTION";
            radcmb.DataValueField ="ID";
            radcmb.DataBind();
```

and i am setting the datasource of the combo box on page_load event, the problem is whenever i have select any item from the combo box and click outside / any other section of the page, its de-select the item and select the first item from the list.

i tried below solution - but it didn't helped me.
[RadComboBox changing selected item when clicking on other parts of page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22934701/radcombobox-changing-selected-item-when-clicking-on-other-parts-of-page)

Comment: That's weird and definitely unexpected behaviour. Can you reproduce it here:

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/configurator/defaultcs.aspx

What's your version of RadControls?

Comment: Are you wrapping your DataBind() logic i if (!Page.IsPostBack)?  If you bind it on every load, you will always get the default selection.